# Pairing function that generates the smallest result

Tags: function, pairing

I noticed that there are various pairing functions, I tried the cantor pairing function which has a ratio of 150% on the final length: `x = 10 chars lenght y = 10 chars lenght CANTOR = 25 chars lenght`, while the Szudzik pairing function has a 100% ratio: `x = 10 chars length y = 10 chars length Szudzik = 20 chars length`, is there another pairing function that has a **0% ratio**? `x = 10 chars length y = 10 chars length Pairing function = 10 chars length.` or in any case *some tabular system* that allows me to find a large number, ***with half the characters***: *548721 -> 254 (example)* Thanks!